# Error: : could not find an object to spy upon for Foo()

Tags: angular, unit-testing, jasmine, karma-jasmine

I tried to create a simple Foo method in my LoyaltyService.

```
    public Foo(): Observable<string> {
    return of('1');
  }
```

injecting it in the spec.ts like this -

```
  //const loyaltyService: LoyaltyService = TestBed.inject(LoyaltyService);
  const loyaltyService: LoyaltyService = fixture.debugElement.injector.get(LoyaltyService);
  spyOn(loyaltyService, 'test').and.returnValue(of('1'));
```

But getting error:
Error:  : could not find an object to spy upon for Foo().
I have tried the TestBed.inject method and also injector.get method.

Comment: What are you actually trying to achieve? Currently it looks like you are trying to stub a method inside a service you are trying to test which is usually not a good idea. You can test observables inside a service. But you would need to give a bit more inside on your service structure and what you want to achieve in the end with your test

Answer (score 0):

when we wrote tests in `AngularJS` and `stub promises` using `SpyOn` we did something like this:

```js
spyOn(someService,'get').and.returnValue(deferred.promise);
```

The code above is completely valid — unlike `observables`, `promises` are always asynchronous. But How to test `Observables`?
Using **`jasmine-marbles`** is the best parctice here. So try something like this:

**app-foo.component.ts**

```js
@Component({
  selector: 'app-foo',
  template: `
    <div class="foo">
      {{ foo | async }}
    </div>
  `
})
export class FooComponent implements OnInit {
  foo: string = "";

  constructor(private fooService: FooService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.fooService.get().subscribe(res => {
      this.foo = res;
    });
  }

}
```

**app-foo.component.spec.ts**

```js
import { cold, getTestScheduler } from 'jasmine-marbles';

const fooServiceStub = {
  get() {
    const foo$ = cold('--x|', { x: `1` });
    return foo$
  }
};

describe('FooComponent', () => {

  it('should work', () => {
    const foo = element.querySelectorAll('.foo');
    getTestScheduler().flush(); // flush the observables
    fixture.detectChanges();
    expect(element.querySelectorAll('.foo').length).toEqual(1);
  });

});
```

For more information about `observables` test see these articles:

[Testing Observables in Angular](https://netbasal.com/testing-observables-in-angular-a2dbbfaf5329)

[How to test Observables](https://medium.com/angular-in-depth/how-to-test-observables-a00038c7faad)